# Problem scanning for \LOGS subfolders with VBS

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I'm using this VBS to scan thru a bunch of directories & subdirectories, and to process only subdirectories ending in `\LOGS`. My code is just not setting  `procIt` to 1 so it never processes those directories. Easy code but I'm missing something:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForAppending = 2
Dim objFSO:Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

scriptdir = replace(WScript.ScriptFullName,WScript.ScriptName,"")
dim dateAndTime 
dim xFolder

' set up log file
xDay = right("0" & Day(Date),2)
xMonth = right("0" & Month(Date),2)
xHours = right("0" & Hour(time),2)
xMins = right("0" & Minute(time),2)
xSecs = right("0" & Second(time),2)
dateAndTime = xDay & "-" & xMonth & "-" & Year(Date) & "_" & xHours & xMins & xSecs
logFile = scriptdir & "log\LogFile_" & dateAndTime & ".log"

Dim objLogFile:Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(logfile, 2, True)

' read folder%
objStartFolder = "C:\test\custom\"

procIt = 0
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
endOf = UCase(Right(objFolder.Path, 5))
If endOf = "\LOGS" then
   procIt = 1
End If
If procIt = 1 then
    objLogFile.Write "Path: " & objFolder.Path & " - " & endOf & procIt & vbCrLf

    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile in colFiles
        objLogFile.Write "File: " & objFile.Name & vbCrLf
        
    Next
End If



ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        procIt = 0
        endOf = UCase(Right(Subfolder.Path, 5))
        If endOf = "\LOGS" Then
            procIt = 1
        End If
        If procIt = 1 Then
            objLogFile.Write Subfolder.Path & " - " & endOf & procIt & vbCrLf
            Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
            Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
            For Each objFile in colFiles
                objLogFile.Write objFile.Name & vbCrLf
            Next
            ShowSubFolders Subfolder
        End If
    Next
End Sub

objLogFile.Close
```

Comment: You could try debugging the code by using `Wscript.Echo` to display variables tom screen to see if values like paths etc match what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

`ShowSubfolders` only looks at the first level of subfolders in its current form.
For example, `logs` folders under `C:\test\custom\first` will never be found because `first` will not change `procIt` to 1.

If you move the recursive call outside of the `If procIt = 1` block it will look at all subfolders, not just the first level, and will find your `logs` folders:

```
Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)

    For Each Subfolder In Folder.SubFolders

        procIt = 0
        endOf = UCase(Right(Subfolder.Path, 5))

        If endOf = "\LOGS" Then procIt = 1

        If procIt = 1 Then
            Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
            Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
            For Each objFile In colFiles
                objLogFile.Write objFile.Name & vbCrLf
            Next
        End If

        ' Call ShowSubFolders recursively to handle subfolders
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder

    Next
End Sub
```